# Passing a character string variable to a filter within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple Shiny app that plots some data.  The app runs a function that accepts 5 arguments and plots the results.

4 of the arguments are passed through a slider and they all work fine but the 5th argument is a text string.

snipit from my UI:

```
selectInput("subsec", "Subsections",
                       c("Pies", "Milk", "Salad", "Bread"),
                         selected = TRUE, multiple = FALSE,
                         selectize=FALSE)
```

Where 'subsec' is the variable I want to pass to my function.

snipit from my server:

```
Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], 
input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], input$subsec[1])
```

This doesn't seem to work and nothing plots but if I manually type in the text string as below it works fine

```
Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], 
input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], Milk)
```

How can I pass the string over?

within my R function I do change the case of the variable to lower case

```
sect <- tolower(deparse(substitute(sect)))
```

Some of the descriptions in the drop down have spaces in them too e.g. Space Invaders.  How can I pass a string with spaces into my function?

Within my function I have some code that manipulates the data based on the 4 numerical arguments, the 5th argument which is a string, filter a data table for the plot.  The code to plot the chart is below:

```
        plot <- (ggplot(data, aes(rank, Move_Curve)) + 
        geom_line(size = 2, color = "blue") +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, x_axis_max + x_axis_incriment, x_axis_incriment)) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20000 + 2000, 500)) + 
        geom_point(data = data[section_lower == sect 
                               & `Price Index` > 0, .(rank, `Price Index`)], aes(y = `Price Index`)) +
        labs(title = "Price Score Optimisation", x = "Product Rank", y = "Optimal Index")
    )

    return(plot)
```

The 'sect' variable is the sting I want to pass to the function in order to be able to filter the data table.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option to pass strings with spaces:

```
selectInput("subsec", "Subsections", 
choices = list("Space invaders" = "space_invaders", "Pies" = "pies"))
```

Try removing `[1]` from `input$subset` to get the first bit to work.

Answer (score 0):

This MVE works fine for me, as expected:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "subsec", "Subsections",
                c("Pies", "Milk", "Salad", "Bread"),
                selected = TRUE, multiple = FALSE,
                selectize=FALSE),
    textOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$text <- renderText({
        sect <- tolower(input$subsec)

        # Apply a function to the selected value
        paste0('The answer is: ', sect)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

To be noted:

- No need to use subsec[1] when selecting the value
- No need to `deparse(substitute())`
- In the example you provided you are not passing a string to the `Price_Score` function, but rather the object `Milk`.

Comment: I can print the selections as you have show but I want to pass the values to a function to create a plot. This is what I have to render the plot

`output$priceplot <- renderPlot({

        Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], input$subsec)

    })`

I can see the 'subsec' value printed on screen but it's not passing it to the function correctly?

Comment: I'd say that's a problem with the `Price_Score` function, but can't be sure without knowing what it does.  
You said that `Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], 
input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], Milk)` works. Is it intended that you pass `Milk` instead of `"Milk"`?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the code to plot the chart within the function.  The plot is in 2 parts, a line made up from the 4 numerical args in the function and a scatter based on 5th text arg from the function.
The plot always works and shows the line but it only shows the scatter when I run the function as below:
`Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], Milk)`

If I surround the word Milk with quotation marks the scatter plot doesn't work.

Comment: try with: `Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], get(input$subsec))`

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to suggest anything without seeing the formula. Does wrapping `as.symbol()` around `input$subsec` work?

```
Price_Score(input$s_ranks[1], input$s_ranks[2], input$s_index[1], input$s_index[2], as.symbol(input$subsec))
```